# How to run dart spark on my own computer?

Tags: ide, dart, dart-spark

I see there is a project named [spark](https://github.com/dart-lang/spark), which is a Chrome app based development environment.

It seems interesting, and I want to run it my own computer(mac os), expected to see a chrome-based IDE for dart. But I can't find any document to tell me how to run it. There are just some pages for how to develop and test, but how to run it?

I tried with the `grind` shell with all kinds of options, but no lucky :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question! The Spark effort is still spinning up, and we're not yet ready for a public release. All the source code is available publicly, so it is possible for people to build it for themselves. Once we're further along we'll put a developer preview release up on the chrome web store.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to build & run Spark IDE on Windows are:

1. Install Dart SDK to e.g. `C:\dart-sdk`
2. Download the Spark source code to e.g. `C:\spark`
3. Open `cmd` and type: `cd C:\Spark`
4. `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\dart-sdk\bin`
5. `set DART_SDK=C:\dart-sdk`
6. `pub get`
7. `grind.cmd deploy`
8. Load the upacked extension from `C:\Spark\ide\build\deploy-out\web` in Chrome Dev.

Alternatively, you can [download Chrome Dev Editor packaged app](http://browsingthenet.blogspot.com/2014/06/download-google-chrome-dev-editor.html), based on Spark 0.13,